# Munkres topology section 17 question 6

Tags: general-topology

Show that the countable collection
{$(a, b) × (c, d) $| $a < b$ and$ c < d$, and $a, b, c, d$ are rational}
is a basis for $R^2.$

I was thinking let us take open set $X \times Y $ for  which $x\in (a,b) \in X$ and $y \in (c,d) \in Y$...now  by definition of the product topology there is  a  basis element of $ x \times y  \in U \times V  \subset  X \times Y$,,,,,,,

now  i can not able to proceed further,,,pliz help me....

Comment: Perhaps you should start by stating exactly what you need to show to prove the desired result.  That is, what is the definition of basis?  Which parts can you show, and which are you stuck on? Also, in your steps above, it was hard to follow your reasoning since you did not define what $U, V, x, y$ were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the reals, every open non-empty open interval contains a rational number.

So if $O$ is open in $R^2$ in the product topology and $(x,y) \in O$, pick $U$ and $V$ open in $R$ such that $x \in U, y \in V$ and $U \times V \subseteq O$. (This can be done by the definition of the product topology).

As $U$ is open in $R$ pick an open interval $(l_x, r_x) \subseteq R$ such that $x \in (l_x,r_x) \subseteq U$. (definition of (order) topology on $R$).

Pick rationals $q_x$ in the open interval $(l_x, x)$ and a rational $q'_x \in (x, r_x)$.

So we have $$x \in (q_x, q'_x) \subseteq (l_x, r_x) \subseteq U$$

Do the same for $y$ and $V$ to get rationals $q_y, q'_y$ such that

$$y \in (q_y, q'_y) \subseteq (l_y, r_y) \subseteq V$$

And note that $$(x,y) \in (q_x, q'_x) \times (q_y, q'_y) \subseteq U \times V \subseteq O$$

and as we can find a member of the countable collection between any open set $O$ of the product topology and a member of $O$. This is exactly what it means to be a base for the product topology.

Comment: thanks  a  lots  Henno sir

Answer (score 1):

Having a grasp of the following two facts is all that is required to answer the OP's question:

(1) The open intervals of the form $(a,b)$, with both $a$ and $b$ rational, forms a basis for $\mathbb R$.

(2) Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces each with a chosen basis.
The set of all ${\displaystyle U \times V}$, where ${\displaystyle U}$ is an element of the basis of ${\displaystyle X}$ and ${\displaystyle V}$ is an element of the basis of ${\displaystyle Y}$, is a basis for the product topology of ${\displaystyle X \times Y}$.

To be able to subscribe to (2), one must know this set theoretic identity:

$\tag 1 \cup \, U_i \times \cup \, V_j = \bigcup_{(i,j)}\; U_i \times V_j$